# executing a repeater item server side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a list of asp:LinkLabels which are contained a repeater.

I have a button that says "Get Started"  when a user clicks on this button, I want it to execute the first item in the repeater.

I have this code working fine in Chrome, but not in any other browser:

```
   <asp:Button ID="SubmitInfo" runat="server" Text="Save and Get Started" Width="218px" OnClientClick="__doPostBack('rptList$ctl01$Label15','')" CssClass="submit-button-huge" OnClick="SubmitInfo_Click" />
```

Is there a way to do this server side without using the __doPostBack javascript?

Is there anything glaringly wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without your whole code. I'll assume your LinkLabels are LinkButtons named "lb1", and you use commandName and CommandArgument, Repeater_ItemCommand

I would try something like this in the repeater.ItemCreated

```
    private void Repeater_ItemCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var lb = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lb1");
            if(IsPostBack && e.Item.ItemIndex==0)
            {
                SubmitInfo.Click+= (source,args)=>Repeater_ItemCommand(lb,new RepeaterCommandEventArgs(e.Item,lb,new CommandEventArgs(lb.CommandName,lb.CommandArgument)));
            }
...
```

Hope this will help